# Analytic function on unit disk has finitely many zeros

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity, conformal-geometry, blaschke-products

I am studying complex analysis from Theodore Gamelin's text and Exercise 1 of chapter IX.2 says that if $f$ is analytic inside the open unit disk and continuous on its boundary that satisfies $|f(z)| = 1$ for $|z| = 1$, then $f$ is a finite Blaschke product. Clearly, this would imply that $f$ has only finitely many zeros in the open unit disk. 
But the proof of it already assumes this fact. 
So my question is that is it trivial that such an $f$ has finitely many zeros in the open unit disk?

Comment: every zero is isolated because $f(a+z) = \sum_n c_n z^n$. and since every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence, if $f$ had infinitely many zeros on a  finite region, one of the zero would be an accumulation point of some sequence of zeros (it wouldn't be isolated). you can also integrate $f'/f$ on a closed contour without zero, it is finite hence $f$ (if it is analytic inside) has a finite number of zeros (counted with multiplicity)

Comment: @user1952009 both arguments makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: just to say that appart maybe the great Picard theorem, nearly every theorems on holomorphic/meromorphic/analytic functions are very easy to prove (once you know the trick / main argument), that's what is so magic with the complex analysis

Comment: @user1952009 The zeros could - theoretically - accumulate to the boundary... But $|f(z)| = 1$ there. So, no. ;-)

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp : yes, '$f$ is analytic inside' was not 100% accurate, $f$ is analytic on an open $U$, then it  has only a finite number of zeros on any compact contained in $U$

Comment: Are there examples of holomorphic functions on bounded domains with infinitely many zeros?

Comment: zeros of $k$th integer order, or zeros which are also singularities/branching points (hence $f$ is not holomorphic at those zeros) ?

Comment: Just zeros. $f(z_n) = 0$ and $z_n\in U$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. $f$ holomorphic on $U$, $U$ open and bounded.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I remember a function analytic on $|z| < 1$ but with an infinity of zeros on $|z| = 1$ and no possible analytic continuation outside (no possibility to go trough that barrier of zeros)

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp  $f(z) = \prod_{k=1}^\infty 1 - z^k$ it converges for $|z| < 1$ because $\ln f(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \ln (1 - z^k)$ which is analytic on $|z| < 1$ ? or maybe $g(z) =  \prod_{n=1}^\infty 1 - z^{2^n}$

Comment: Ok, thank you. But that is actually not what I asked for. ;-)

Comment: I found such a function (by googling): $f(z) = \sin(1/(1+z))$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb D$ and has infinitely many zeros there. The sequence converges to $-1$, where the function has an essential singularity.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp : right, it is analytic on $D : \{z \ \mid \ |z| < 1\}$, hence it has finitely many zeros on any compact $\subset D$, but an infinity of zeros on $D$. the counterpart is an essential singularity at $z= -1$.   that's an instructive example for the original question, tks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{D}$ denote the open unit disc. In general, an analytic function $f:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{C}$ is allowed to have countably many zeros in $\mathbb{D}$. As Friedrich has pointed out,
$$
\sin\left(\frac{1}{1+z}\right)
$$
is an example of a function that is analytic on $\mathbb{D}$ and has infinitely zeros inside $\mathbb{D}$.

However, if we assume that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{D}$, and also that $|f(z)| = 1$ for $|z|=1$, then the story changes. Suppose $f$ has countably many zeros $z_n$ in $\mathbb{D}$. Then by compactness, the set $\{z_n\}$ has a limit point in $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$.

The zeros cannot have a limit point on boundary of the unit disc, since if $z_{n_k}\to z_\infty\in\partial\mathbb{D}$ then $f(z_{n_k})\to f(z_\infty)$ by continuity, but $|f(z_{n_k})| = 0$ and $|f(z_\infty)| = 1$, contradiction.

So the limit point in $\mathbb{\overline{\mathbb{D}}}$ must lie inside $\mathbb{D}$. But then $f$ has a sequence of zeros converging inside its domain of definition, and since $f$ is analytic it follows that $f \equiv 0$. This is a contradiction if $f$ is assumed nontrivial.

Therefore it follows that if $f$ is nontrivial, then $f$ can only have finitely many zeros inside $\mathbb{D}$. At this point one can express $f$ as a product of finitely many Blaschke factors using a consequence of the Schwarz lemma.

Comment: If $f$ is only assumed to be analytic in the open unit disk and $|f(z)|\rightarrow 1$ as $|z|\rightarrow 1$, then would $f$ still have finitely many zero? I am thinking we can extend $f$ to be analytic in a neighborhood of the boundary of the unit disk and then apply the same argument as above.